# Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Usuario[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more

Tags: angular, api, vscode

Me salen estos dos errores en this.listUsuarios y en getUsuario() Como los soluciono?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia la imagen por código en formato texto. No todos podemos ver las imágenes y transcribir de la imagen para tratar de reproducir tu código no es lo más adecuado. Te invito a leer [mre] para que apliques eso en tu pregunta y tengas más posibilidades de obtener respuesta. Saludos

Comment: No editas la pregunta, no atiendes lo que te dicen en la respuesta. Pero quieres una respuesta. Está muy difícil así, camarada

Comment: Como se soluciona este error,@Alfabravo?

Comment: No puedo dejarte hacer esto.. a ver.. esta pregunta, sobre postman y acceso a la api, tenia una respuesta que aceptaste... Tu segunda pregunta, que borraste, es la que deberias recuperar y sobre la cual hay que trabajar. Voy a revertir esta, y trabajemos sobre la otra.. tratamos de ayudarte, pero solo nos estas mareando y dando mas trabajo :(

Comment: @gbianchi AAAAAAAH!!! La segunda pregunta que borre que era sobre del return ya esta solucionado! Y ahora estoy editando esta primera pregunta en modo texto para que la puedas ver mejor en vez de poner imagenes y en la segunda pregunta pondre en modo texto lo que se ve en usuario.service.ts! Es una pregunta en dos partes!!

Comment: no no.. a ver.. esta pregunta, como estaba antes, TIENE UNA RESPUESTA.. no podes cambiar la pregunta, porque entonces, la respuesta deja de tener sentido, y quien invirtio su tiempo en eso, LO PERDIO, y no le sirve a nadie la pregunta ni la respuesta, si no tienen sentido... por mas que edites esta pregunta, la original ya tenia respuesta. Se te pidio que hicieras otra pregunta, que hiciste, y luego borraste... Si queres, recupera y edita esa pregunta, para tener una pregunta de seguimiento...

Comment: @gbianchi Listo,ya edite la pregunta que borre a modo texto en vez de poner imagenes,ahora si lo ves mejor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Dónde estás usando Postman? ¿Qué es listUsuarios? ¿Dónde usas el HttpClient?

Postman no esta dentro de Angular, ni siquiera dentro de VS Code, es un programa aparte que sirve para probar y construir APIs.

Empecemos por resolver la confusión que tienes en el código, es muy simple.

En el constructor:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Para obtener datos:

```
  getUsuario(id: string): Observable<Usuario> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/?consultar=1${id}`);
  }
```

Como ves, solamente tienes que usar el HttpClient para hacer los requests, por otra parte parece que tu url ya trae un ID por defecto (`=1`) así que probablemente quieras quitarlo. Otra cosa, no uses `any`, porque luego no vas a saber que es lo que recibes o envías, así te ahorras problemas.

Por otro lado, viendo la estructura de proyecto que tienes, te recomiendo leer [Buenas prácticas en Angular](https://medium.com/angular-chile/buenas-pr%C3%A1cticas-en-angular-74663897c059)

Comment: Si,pero tambien pasa lo mismo con ,post y delete

Comment: Se resuelve igual, fijate bien en el código. Pregúntate a ti mismo que es `listUsuarios` y porque lo estas usando en lugar de http.

Comment: Te voy a explicar,estoy haciendo un proyecto de Angular que es un login,eso ya esta hecho que es la parte visual y funciona bien. Pero ahora lo que me pidieron es que este proyecto que tengo,lo conecte con un URL de una api que me mandaron asi al momento de usar Postman veo si funciona

Comment: Yo ya se que estás haciendo, pero no parece que sepas tu que es lo que estas haciendo en el servicio. Estás usando un arreglo de Usuario para hacer peticiones http. `listUsuarios.get`, `listUsuarios.post`, `listUsuarios.delete`, ¿por qué lo usas? Ahí esta el error.

Comment: Porque el listUsuarios es para meter los usuarios que quiero añadir o quitar al momento de entrar al navegador

Comment: ¿Y desde cuando los arreglos hacen peticiones http? ¿Entonces para que es el HttpClient? Si quieres iniciar sesión / registrar y eliminar usuarios tendrías que mandar los datos en el body del request. No hay explicación lógica para lo que estás haciendo, revisa el tutorial sobre cómo hacer peticiones http [Obtener datos desde un servidor](https://docs.angular.lat/tutorial/toh-pt6).

Comment: Escucheme,el proyecto que tengo hecho con Angular que es la parte visual y funciona bien para iniciar sesion con el usuario y contraseña que programe,al igual que los usuarios que he metido, lo unico que me falta es hacer la conexion con Postman metiendo una API que me dieron y con eso ya estaria hecho.

Comment: Parece que aún no has entendido, los arreglos NO hacen peticiones Http. Para eso esta HttpClient en Angular, en Javascript usarías `fetch` o Axios, no tiene ningún sentido en el mundo hacer algo como `return this.listUsuarios.post`.  Dices que te quieres conectar a Postman, pero Postman es para probar y construir APIs, quieres que te escuche pero no tienes las ideas claras. Si quieres registrar un usuario tendrías que hacer algo como: 
`registrar(name: string, email: string, password: string) {
    const body = { name, email, password };
    return this.http.post<any>(url, body);
  }`

Comment: En el tutorial que comente viene muy bien explicado como hacer un CRUD básico que parece es lo que necesitas hacer (iniciar sesión, registrar, eliminar usuarios, actualizar usuarios). Si aún no te queda claro lo del arreglo, revisa [Array - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Los comentarios no son para hacer un chat. Pueden ir al [chat]. PD. El amigo @LautaroCuesta no está leyendo lo que le están diciendo y así es muy difícil recibir una respuesta

Comment: A ver señor @René,dejeme que le cuente,el error anterior que le comente sobre el get,post y delete estan resueltos,lo de poner "return this.listUsuarios.post" no lo puse asi tal cual,le cambie el "listUsuarios" por otro nombre que puse al lado izquierdo de los dos puntos del HttpClient donde se encuentra el constructor,por ejemplo puse constructor(private conexionservicio: HttpClient) { } y luego puse return this.conexionservicio.get(this.API+"?consultar=1"+id); y asi me funciono. Pero ahora el siguiente error esta en el return,que ahora le explico cual es

Comment: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Usuario>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Usuario': usuario, nombre, apellido, genero. Este es el error que me sale en el return

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que debo de saber que es lo que hiciste o no? En ningún momento actualizaste el código ni comentaste algo sobre eso. Traduce el error y ya está, más fácil: cambia `Object` por `Usuario`

Comment: Para responder a las aclaraciones se edita la pregunta. Si no usan el sitio como es, la pregunta termina cerrada, gente

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero las preguntas para aclaraciones se realizan como comentario. Puedes primero consultar al OP y responder con base en esta información.